# How to refresh In-memory Cache Data from database in every 30 min .Net-Core

Tags: caching, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, in-memory

I wants to refresh or update my in-memory cache data in every 30 min in .Net Core
Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean 'from database', is it a database cache?

Comment: No, It is just .net core InMemoryCache. i stored some data in startup of project after each 30 min I want to pull new data and update in my cache.